# Wrong dimensions when trying to use model.predict() from Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I think the code will speak for itself, but i trained a model, that i now wanna use to predict on some new input data. The new input data seems to be the wrong dimensions though. Below you can see the code and error messages for both the model and the predicting (attempted)

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)

df = pd.read_csv('/home/paperspace/Sentiment Analysis Dataset.csv', index_col = 0,
                 error_bad_lines = False)

y = list(df['Sentiment'])

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(df['SentimentText']))
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list(df['SentimentText']))
X = pad_sequences(X)

print("Done, fitting on texts.")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, shuffle = True)

model = Sequential()
#Creates the wordembeddings.
embedding_vector_dim = 32
model.add(Embedding(10000, embedding_vector_dim, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))         
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


model.fit(numpy.array(X_train), numpy.array(y_train),
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=1,
          validation_data=(numpy.array(X_test), numpy.array(y_test)))
score, acc = model.evaluate(numpy.array(X_test),numpy.array(y_test),
                            batch_size=128)

model.save('./sentiment_seq.h5')

print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

Now for the trying to predict and error message.

```
text = "this is actually a very bad movie."
tokenizer = Tokenizer()

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(text))
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list(text))
X = pad_sequences(X)
X_flat = np.array([X.flatten()])


model = load_model('sentiment_test.h5')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.predict(X, batch_size = 1, verbose = 1))

ValueError: Error when checking : expected embedding_1_input to have shape (None, 116) but got array with shape (1, 38)
```

So basically why am i getting this error, when preprocessing is the same when training and predicting, and how can i know what the expected input should be before seeing the error message?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not working with a fixed input length, you should not define an `input_length` in the embedding layer.

Comment: I've seem to figured it out. I've assumed i used a fixed input as i padded the sentences, and apparently have to figure out what the X.shape[1] is and pad all new inputs to that length as well, when predicting.